# How to create an audio spectrum using JavaScript and HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Ok, so I know how to animate a canvas using [AnalyserNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/frequencyBinCount). I made a demo of how I implemented it.

*This is my demo* ->
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-lovelace-bmwxo?file=/src/Visualizer.js

What I am trying to understand is how do I make this look similar to this -> https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/storycreator.rendered/cka4ubx6d0dgb0114ws1rll7p?t=1590039817915

This audio spectrum was generated in After Effects using the audio spectrum effect.

I am using `new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount)` the frequency feedback from the audio api. What is AE using under the hood to create the spectrum effect and is there a difference between spectrum and frequency in this context?

Here is the full code for JavaScript frequency

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

let frequencyArray = [];
let analyser;

const Visualizer = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const requestRef = useRef(null);

  const handleInit = () => {
    initAudio();
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
  };

  const initAudio = () => {
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.src =
      "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.uploads/ck9kpb5ss0xf90132mgf8z893?client_id=d8976b195733c213f3ead34a2d95d1c1";
    audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    audio.load();

    const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    audio.play();
  };

  // draw the whole thing
  const drawCanvas = () => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const radius = 200;
      const bars = Math.round(canvas.width);

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyArray);

      for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        const height = frequencyArray[i] * 0.25;

        drawLine(
          {
            i,
            bars,
            height,
            radius
          },
          canvas,
          ctx
        );
      }

      requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
    }
  };

  // dray lines around the circle
  const drawLine = (opts, canvas, ctx) => {
    const { i, radius, bars, height } = opts;
    const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    const lineWidth = 10;

    // draw the bar
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY + height);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY - height);
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleInit}>Start Visualizer</button>
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        style={{ background: "#f5f5f5" }}
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Visualizer;
```

Comment: I'm really curious about the main difference in the approach. I am setting the height in my version but what do you think AE is doing in terms of using the frequency to change the bars? Is the frequency data just different? Or can you change something other than just the height?

Comment: Your Demo looks good to me ... Can you be more specific on what "similar" effect are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I made a few tweaks to your demo, look here: https://orumf.csb.app/  If you want to get the animation less "spiky" we will need to some math to do some rounding

Answer (score 3):

I think [`analyzer.getByteTimeDomainData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteTimeDomainData) would be more appropriate.

A slightly modified version of your code(so that I could test it offline and because I am not familiar with React):

```js
let frequencyArray = [];
let analyser;
let request;
var flag=0;
var height=0;

const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const bars = Math.round(canvas.width);
const lineWidth = 3;


var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;


const audio = new Audio();
audio.src =
  "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.uploads/ck9kpb5ss0xf90132mgf8z893?client_id=d8976b195733c213f3ead34a2d95d1c1";
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
audio.load();

const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  context.resume().then(() => {
    console.log('Playback resumed successfully');
  });
});

  function begin()
  {
     audio.play();
     requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
  };

  function end()
  {
    cancelAnimationFrame(request);
    audio.pause();
  };

audio.addEventListener("ended", close);

function close()
{
  if(flag==0)
  {
    flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      flag=0;
  }
}


  const drawCanvas = () => {

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray);

      for (var i = 0; i < bars; i+=3) {
       height = frequencyArray[i];
       
       if(height<100)
       {
        height*=0.05;
       }
       else
       {
        if(height<200 && height>100)
        {
          height=(height-100)+(100*0.05)
        }
        else
        {
          height=(height-200)*0.2+(100*1.05);
        }
       }

        drawLine(
          {
            i,
            bars,
            height
          },
          canvas,
          ctx
        );
      }

      if(flag==0)
      {
      request = requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
      }
      else
      {
        flag=2;
        close();
      }
  };


  const drawLine = (opts, canvas, ctx) => {
    const { i, bars, height } = opts;

    // draw the bar
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#212121";
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY + height);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY - height);
    ctx.stroke();


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

<button id="button" onClick=begin()>Start</button>
<button onClick=end()>End</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

<script src = "wave.js">

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Intermittently some sharp spikes emerge which looks bad. Perhaps someone else can fix that.

Comment: `getByteTimeDomainData` draws [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/805619612770238474/937028630373077002/unknown.png) instead of [what the asker was looking for](https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/33184129/preview/stock-footage-colorful-bright-abstract-audio-spectrum-lines-background.webm)